# Should I put server-side listeners on io or socket for socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

If I have my `express.js` server set up as such:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

server.listen(8080);
```

And elsewhere I have a `io.on('connnect', function(socket){...});` , should I be putting emit/event listeners on that socket within the `io.connect(...)` callback, or on the io object?

My basic program flow is as follows:

1. Client socket emits `get_new_number`.
2. Server receives `get_new_number` from unique socket.
3. Based on that unique socket ID, it `emits` `new_number`
4. The client listens for `new_number` and logs the data within to the console when triggered.

On the server-side, for part 2, I believe that must be a within the `io.on('connect'...)` function, so I can access `socket.id` for use later :

```
io.on('connect', function(socket){
    socket.on('get_new_number', function(){
        console.log('server got request for new number.');
        globalVarId = socket.id;        
    });
});
```

But from there, where should I emit a new number to that unique socket? Say I save the `socket.id` and then emit to only it, how can I do that? The below isn't working:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket){
    //get_new_number stuff
    socket.to(globalVarId).emit('new_number', {number: someNumber});
});
```

Should I instead later do a `io.to(globalVarId).emit...` ?

EDIT: For that matter, is there a way to put event listeners on the `io` object, such like

```
io.on('someEvent', function(socket){
    console.log('this socket did a thing, ', socket.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume that `socket` within the callback function represents a unique client/connection.

So when you want to communicate with that client, you can use `socket.emit()`:

```
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
  socket.on('get_new_number', function() {
    console.log('server got request for new number.');
    //get_new_number stuff
    socket.emit('new_number', { number: someNumber });
  });
});
```

`.to(...).emit(...)` is used for something else entirely (sending a message to a particular [room](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms)).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So the `to` and `in` stuff is for one socket to `emit` to another socket/room, then? I guess if I want to do "channel-wide" emitting, i.e. from the `io` object or really just from my server, I need to be doing the redis stuff they mention at the bottom of the docs here? : http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: On your edit: I was using `to` and `emit` to get messages to a unique socket, as in the docs they say that each socket gets automatically joined to a room named after that `socket.id`, which confused me into thinking that's the only way to address one unique socket.

Comment: @komali_2 so you want the server to receive a message from one client, and send the response to another client? **EDIT**: never mind, I think I understand what you mean now :-) `.to()` and `.in()` are used to send messages to other clients in a particular room, if you want to address the client that sent the message originally, you use `socket.emit()`.

Comment: Gotcha, that really helps clarify. I'm just going to blame poor docs rather than my generally confusion!